# How to answer a question which already has acceptable answers and my answer will add at most 5% to the existing answers

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Few hours ago I answered the question [reading file without newlines in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-file-without-newlines-in-python). The problem is that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58199105/1772898) is made up of existing answers with probably 5% tweak. I did it to facilitate future reference.

I am sort of feeling guilty because people will probably updvote my answer though I am not the primary contributor. And I am also probably depriving those who helped me find a solution.

What is the proper way to make these sort of contributions?

Comment: You _could_ mark the answer as "Community Wiki", in which case no upvotes will accrue to your reputation.  To be honest, I'd avoid making this kind of answer unless it adds significant value, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: A bit similar to [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/10063119) "*Post an answer with the solution in the comments, and make it Community Wiki by checking the Community Wiki box.*" - Robert Harvey

Comment: There's no need to feel guilty. You're giving attribution to the authors of the code you adapted. And you're unlikely to score a lot of votes on an answer to a 7 year old question that already has lots of answers.